# Issue using the count function in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, count

I am running this query to get a count of the bookedby users total number of sales with insurance and total number of sales without insurance. However, all of the users are getting the same count for some reason. how can i change my query to show each users totals instead.

**what i want is basically to figure out how many bookings each user had with and without insurance sales**

bookedby is the agent

and T0 is the table that includes the information about bookings that do not include insurance

and t1 is the table that includes information about bookings with insurance

while both tables provide the same information how can i get a total by booked by for each agent from both tables

```
 SELECT   t0.BookedBy, count(t0.resnumber) as NonInsurance, COUNT(t1.resnumber) as Insurance  
    FROM (SELECT BookedBy, ResNumber, DATEPART(year, BookDate) AS Year, DATEPART(month, BookDate) AS month
              FROM dbo.ResGeneral
              WHERE ResNumber NOT IN (SELECT ResNumber FROM dbo.ResItinerary_insurance) 
                  and  ResStatus = 'a'
              GROUP BY BookedBy, ResNumber, BookDate) t0 
        left JOIN (SELECT BookedBy, ResNumber, DATEPART(year, BookDate) AS Year, DATEPART(month, BookDate) AS month
                       FROM dbo.ResGeneral
                       WHERE ResNumber IN (SELECT ResNumber FROM dbo.ResItinerary_insurance)
                           and  ResStatus = 'a') t1         
            ON t1.year = t0.year         
    group by t0.bookedby
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this query is equivalent:

```
SELECT g.BookedBy,
       SUM(CASE WHEN i.ResNumber IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NonInsurance,
       SUM(CASE WHEN i.ResNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Insurance
    FROM dbo.ResGeneral g
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ResItinerary_insurance i
            ON g.ResNumber = i.ResNumber
    WHERE g.ResStatus = 'a'
    GROUP BY g.BookedBy;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your join condition looks incorrect:

```
 ON t1.year = t0.year
```

This will cross join *all* rows with the same year. You probably want to use a more specific condition, for example `t1.BookedBy = t0.BookedBy`.

Comment: hmm that didnt work because i am not trying to sum the actual res number. what i want is basically to figure out how many bookings each user had with and without insurance sales.

Comment: the problem with t1.BookedBy = t0.BookedBy  was that not all agents have a booking in both tables

Comment: @bugz: `t1.BookedBy = t0.BookedBy` on a LEFT OUTER JOIN doesn't require that all agents have a booking in both tables... only in the LEFT table (hence *LEFT* OUTER JOIN). Do you want a *FULL* OUTER JOIN perhaps? This will include rows from both tables.